# Conditional statement if date in cell is 'today'

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2007, conditional-formatting

I'm trying to basically do: IF A1 is Today then highlight/bold/whatever B1 through F1.

Specifically I want to select a range of cells for the rule to apply to but I don't know how to write the IF statement in the "Use a formula to determine which cells to format" section

Answer (score 1):

Please select B1:F1 HOME > Styles - Conditional Formatting, New Rule..., *Use a formula to determine which cells to format* and **Format values where this formula is true:**:

```
=$A1=TODAY()
```

<kbd>Format...</kbd>, select choice of formatting, OK, OK.

Because CF is *Conditional* Formatting an `IF` statement is not normally required (it is assumed) - just a formula that returns TRUE.